# Query to Dissolve Nearby Polygons on Hive

Tags: postgis, dissolve, hive, hadoop, spatial-framework-hadoop

I am using the [ESRI spatial framework for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop), that extends Hive to use spatial types and operations.

My objective is to translate a set of simple queries on PostGIS into Hadoop, in order to reach horizontal scalability.

I have a grid with a count for each cell.

[image]

The objective of my query is to select all cells that have a count higher than a certain threshold, and group(merge) all cells that are together. For instance in this case, I would end up with something like this: 4 polygons.

[image]

To do this in PostGIS, I use a combination of [ST_Dump](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) and [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html)

```
CREATE TABLE exploded AS
SELECT
(ST_Dump(st_union)).geom
FROM  (SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001)) 
 FROM grid where ptcnt > 'threshold) as q;
```

Unfortunately, none of these functions is available on [ESRI's spatial framework](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/blob/master/hive/function-ddl.sql).

I can perform the threshold filter, but I have no way of aggregating the nearby geometries based on the proximity (a trick perform by the grid):

```
create table exploded as select u as geom from (select geom as u from grid_cnt where ptcnt > 11467) as q;
```

[image]

Does anybody can think of a workaround (perhaps using Union)?

Comment: Interesting question and thanks for the pointer. I work with pretty large datasets in Postgres, and have been wondering how to parallelize some of my queries. I have played with Hadoop a bit, but not Hive, and didn't know about this ESRI Hadoop stuff at all. As to your question, it is a shame there is no ST_Expand, but you might be able to use Buffer in conjuntion with Union as a proxy? Obviously, this is less precise than Snap_To_Grid, but if there is nothing in the neighbouring cell, nothing will get unioned.

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot for the comment. I already though about replacing the ST_SnapToGrid with St_Buffer, but I would still need the ST_Dump to collect the results of the grouping...

Comment: You can't use ST_Union in conjunction with WHERE ST_Intersects, ie, only union those that intersect, to avoid having to dump again. To be honest, I am not sure from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677333/how-to-write-subquery-and-use-in-clause-in-hive) if Hive would even support this kind of query. Maybe I should shut up and leave it to the experts.

Comment: Do you go to any meetup groups in Barcelona? I am always happy to meet people interested in spatial and big data.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes go to "urban beers", that also covers geospatial topics and "Barcelona Free Software". What about you?

Comment: I will join urban beers :D I go to the Python meetup sometimes.

Comment: Have you tried `ST_Aggr_Union`?  Though it should give you a single multipolygon instead of 4 polygons.

Answer (score 1):

The `ST_Bin` and `ST_BinEnvelope` functions (added in 2014) may help in place of `ST_SnapToGrid`.  There is an example in [step 4 of this tutorial](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/wiki/Getting-the-results-of-a-Hive-query-into-ArcGIS).

The `ST_Aggr_Union` function may also be useful.  There is an example in [the blog post announcing the aggregate functions](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/16/st_geometry-aggregate-functions-for-hive-in-spatial-framework-for-hadoop/).

(Disclosure: I am a collaborator on the GIS Tools for Hadoop at Esri.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer: it gave me indeed some good pointers. I think the St_Aggr_Union could be a good solution for my problem, but unfortunately I cannot get it to work. I wrote a post here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131141/error-using-st-geometry-aggregate-function-for-hive . Can you help?

Comment: We are looking at that that one and will comment on it.

Comment: As also mentioned under the other question, the ST_Aggr_Union example from the blog post, works for us on Hive 0.14, 0.13, and 0.12 with Hadoop 2.2 .

Comment: Based on your comment I assume you haven't tried with latest release of Hadoop (2.6.)...

Comment: Correct, we do not yet have Hadoop-2.6 with which to test.

Comment: As commented in linked Q/A, collaborator/colleague Sarah has tested with Hadoop-2.6, and did not encounter an error.

Comment: A fork with a commit about "[jdk1.7, hadoop2.6.0, hive1.2.1](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/commit/d3d691fa6a8e8124ffbd2033f78f3d86f5fc3a11)" changes only the `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Input: a grid named ("polygon_grid"), with the names of the "id" and "count" fields shown in the figure below.

[image]

Output: merged cells by a certain value.

Execute the query:

```
WITH 
tbla AS (SELECT id, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM polygon_grid WHERE count<=185 OR count>=963 GROUP BY id)
SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM (SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM tbla) foo;
```

See the figure below for the result.

[image]

I played with the data in EPSG 4326.

Original solutions...