# Error using ST_Geometry Aggregate Function for Hive

Tags: spatial-database, hive, hadoop, spatial-framework-hadoop

I am using the [ESRI framework](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop) that extends the Hive syntax to support spatial types and operations.

In particular, I am trying to use an aggregated geometry function, announced in [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/16/st_geometry-aggregate-functions-for-hive-in-spatial-framework-for-hadoop/) in 2013.

What I would like to do, is to generate a bunch of buffers around some points, and then dissolve them using ST_Aggr_Union.

```
create table buffers as select ST_Aggr_Union(ST_Buffer(tweets.geom,0.5)) as geom from tweets join grid_cnt where ST_Contains(grid_cnt.geom,tweets.geom)=true and ptcnt>6;
```

The query fails with a Map Reduce error:

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2015-01-21 12:55:21,758 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local1494455277_0007 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://localhost:8080/
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-2:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

If I do the query **without** the ST_Aggr_Union function, it runs without problems.

Just to be sure, I also tried to reproduce the example in the [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/16/st_geometry-aggregate-functions-for-hive-in-spatial-framework-for-hadoop/):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Aggr_Union(ST_Point(earthquakes.longitude, earthquakes.latitude)))
FROM earthquakes
JOIN counties_json counties
WHERE counties.name = ‘San Bernardino’
AND earthquakes.magnitude > 6
AND ST_Contains(counties.shape, ST_Point(earthquakes.longitude, earthquakes.latitude));
```

It fails, with the exact same error. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Interesting, so ST_Aggr_Union is an ESRI invention.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if they did. Esri's ST_GEOMETRY implementation dates back to the late 90s on DB2 and Informix (SDE 3.1.1, I believe), which was ported to Oracle at 9.2 and PostgreSQL at 9.3. The standards were under development at the time, but Esri usually had one of the first compliant implementations

Comment: Which version of Hive are you running for this?

Comment: The latest stable release: 0.14.0

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to recreate.  In the meantime, can you look in the logs for more information on why the MR job failed?

Comment: Thanks for that. Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/pDR0kDTP

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce with `0.14.0`.  1) Which version of Hive are you using and 2) Can you look at the tasktracker logs and also the Hive execution log `Execution log at: /tmp/hduser/hduser_20150121173939_3c81cfdd-85d0-4cb4-a894-83a102602ebf.log`

Comment: As I said on a previous comment, I am using Hive 0.14.0; I am also using Hadoop 2.6.0 and esri-tools for hadoop 2.0. The Execution log you asked me is here: http://pastebin.com/pDR0kDTP . I am not sure how to get the tasktracker log. thanks

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to ask which version of **Hadoop** you're using.  Thanks.  I will have to get a Hadoop 2.6 instance to test with.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error using Hortonworks sandbox 2.2, with Hadoop 2.6.